# Using Wildcard in C# to get the string of a dynamic generated file?

Tags: c#, string, wildcard

this is my first question here in stack overflow. 
this is my current problem and question that i wish to solve

i have this dynamically generated file which is generated everyday

```
"EDIOut5_20170112_063449.csv"
```

and i want to move it to another directory.
I'm currently using `System.IO.File.Move()`

My main problem is when i try to call the string this part of the code is generated at random

```
"063449"
```

so it ends like this.

```
 string fileName = "EDIOut"+ dayOfWeekplus + "_" + shortDate + "_" + "063449" + ".csv";
```

The question is. Can i use a wildcard in C# to substitute the random generated part in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to break the task up into 2 steps...

1. File files using [Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) to find files matching a specific pattern (notice the `*` character is a wildcard)
2. Move the found files using [File.Move()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sample code:

```
// use wildcard pattern containing *
string pattern = "EDIOut"+ dayOfWeekplus + "_" + shortDate + "_" + "*" + ".csv"
// get list of files matching pattern
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\your\path\here\", pattern);
// move found files to new location
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    System.IO.File.Move(files[i], @"c:\new\path\" + Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 6 minutes! I was going to suggest regex as well.